# Proof a direct sum of vector spaces generates an entire space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

For,
$$U=\{(x_1,...x_n)\in\mathbb{F}^n\vert x_1+...+x_n=0\} \text{ and }V=\{(x_1,...x_n)\in\mathbb{F}^n\vert x_1=...=x_n\},$$
I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{F}^n=U\oplus V$.

I know I need to show that $(1)$ $\mathbb{F}^n=U+ V$ and $(2)$ $V\cap U=\{0\}$. I can easily show $(2)$, but I have no idea how to show $(1)$. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I would appreciate solutions not involving isomorphisms/mappings between isomorphic sets since I have not yet learned enough about these in my studies of linear algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $T: \mathbb{F}^n \to U \oplus V$ given by $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mapsto (x_1 - \bar x, \ldots, x_n - \bar x, \bar x, \ldots, \bar x)$ where $\bar x = n^{-1}(x_1 + \ldots + x_n)$, and show that this is an isomorphism. This works if $\mathbb{F}$ has characteristic $0$ or the characteristic does not divide $n$. The given proposition is false if the characteristic does divide $n$: take for example $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $n=2$. Then $U = V = \operatorname{span}\{(1, 1)\} \neq \mathbb{F}^2$.

Edit: The basic idea is that every $x \in \mathbb{F}^n$ can be written as a sum $u + v$ where $v$ is the vector having as its components the average of the components of $x$, and $u$ is the component-wise deviation from the average. Then it is easy to show that $u \in U$ and $v \in V$.

Comment: I would appreciate solutions not involving isomorphisms/mappings between isomorphic sets since I have not yet learned enough about these in my studies of linear algebra. I also do not see how this works or why you may have constructed $\tilde{x}$ in such a way.

Comment: I do very much appreciate this counter example however.

Comment: Edited my answer, hope that helps.

Comment: thanks a lot, that helped me understand this much better. This seems like a very clever trick that I'd never be able to come up with on my own.